# Unable to sync files using OneDrive for Business client on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, sync, onedrive

Running OneDrive for Business on Windows 7 x64

Symptoms are:

1. No green checkmarks next to the OneDrive folders
2. If I right click on any of the folders, the "OneDrive for Business" context menu is greyed out

[image: http://snag.gy/tkmfJ.jpg]

What I've tried:

1. A complete (and clean) uninstall of MS Office 2013 - twice.
   Note: after a re-install, it works. But then, after restarting the machine, I'm back to the same problem again
2. Running both quick and online repair
   http://office.microsoft.com/en-ca/outlook-help/repair-office-programs-HA010357402.aspx

Any suggestions are appreciated. It looks like my account gets "disconnected", but I do not see any option to sign back into OneDrive.

I am able to access existing files within the client (via Windows Explorer), but not able to upload/sync new ones.

Comment: Also, are you sure that both OneDrive for Business and the rest of your Office Suite are the same bit versions? I've read online that that can cause a conflict if you have a 64 bit Office & 32 bit OneDrive.

Comment: You won't be able to install a 32 bit OneDrive with 64 bit Office (or vice-versa)

Answer (score 1):

Based on this thread, it appears that the issue is with OneDrive's September update.

http://community.office365.com/en-us/f/154/t/264407.aspx

Solution is to wait it out until the next update is ready. Until then, the workaround is to use the web based version.